# Mask RCNN detecting object but mask is inaccurate

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition, faster-rcnn

I am trying to detect the inner region of a object. Currently I am using the mask rcnn implementation provided by tensorflow in the models zoo.

The object is similar to a hula hoop that is square in shape. [image]

I tried the inception_V2 backbone and have about 3000 images from different angles and lighting conditions.

After about 20,000 steps the model seems to converege to ~0.2 (seems reasonable based on other examples of mask rcnn on the internet) and stay there for as long as I run it. I have tried upto 200,000 steps.

The problem I am having is that while the bounding box is correctly drawn, the mask is inaccurate. Instead of the ground truth mask which has well defined edges, I get wavy edges and overshoots/undershoots. ([image: prediction image]

My goal is to find the 4 corner points of the inner area and am unable to. Any suggestions? Is there a way to post process these masks?

Is it also possible to find the inner edges maybe from the bounding box? I tried classical methods but could not manage to get the inner area.